# Searching for a repo in Github APIv3

Tags: search, github-api

I know how to search for a repository by providing key words in Github APIv2 .But is this possible in the APIv3? 
http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html
It says 
"This API is deprecated. Check out API v3 for the latest documentation."
But I would like to do the same search operation in APIv3. Is this possible?
Please help.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository search is now currently supported using API v3.

The documentation is available [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories).

Comment: Ok Thanks . Just thought there might be a way  :(

Comment: What was the reason for such deprecation?