# How to pull the public information from GitHub repos using Ruby

Tags: ruby, git, github, github-api

Is there any way to retrieve public GitHub repository information via an Ruby API?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the [github-api-client](https://github.com/farnoy/github-api-client) gem, it covers v2 and v3 of the API. There's also [Octopi](https://github.com/fcoury/octopi), but it only supports v2 and hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Is there any way to search the public repositories in git?

Comment: Search doesn't currently work in v3 but still works in v2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310657/searching-for-a-repo-in-github-apiv3

Comment: Or any way to get all public repository information from git?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the github specific API myself since it ties your application to use *only* github rather than a general remote git repository. It also makes you dependent on their API which is probably not a good idea.

The [grit](http://grit.rubyforge.org/) gem gives you read/write access to a git repository. I would use that to handle your problem.

Comment: This is good advice, but Rafiu specififally asked about GitHub metadata like description, number of watchers and forks, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to find the public repositories using this gem?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Your edited version of the question makes it clear that that's what the OP intended. Not so with the original wording.

Comment: @Rafiu Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Github provides some RESEful API for you to access http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/

You certainly can use http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client gem to wrap around Git API and pull the information you need.

Comment: There are dedicated gems for the API, no need to wrap it yourself.